# Riak: is $bucket safe in production?

Tags: riak

I need to clean a few buckets in a massive riak database. For certain buckets, since we had indexes, I just queried those and deleted the keys. But now I'm dealing with two buckets that don't have any indexes. As I read many many times I shouldn't use `keys?keys=true` or `keys?keys=stream` on production systems, however another way of getting all the keys is to use the `$bucket` index, as suggested [in the documentation](https://www.tiot.jp/riak-docs/riak/kv/2.0.0/developing/usage/secondary-indexes/#retrieve-all-bucket-keys-via-the-bucket-index), which doesn't warn of not using this in production. I believe this was also known as `$keys` previously. Our system seems to work with either.

However, just before running this on production I've been playing around and found that the `$bucket` index returns keys that were deleted, just like `keys?keys=true`/`stream`, while this was not the case when I used the indexes that we were maintaining ourselves.

Is the $bucket index safe to use in production?

Note that our system runs on the **LevelDB** backend, which I've been told is bucket scoped, and therefore it would be safe to even run `keys?keys=true`/`stream` on it. Is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reality is that there are no guarantees when using $bucket or $key, especially if you combine with Map/Reduce, that they will not impact the stability of the cluster.  However, if you know there to be a relatively small number of keys in a bucket, or if you use max_results in your query - then $bucket should be relatively safe (certainly a lot better than using list keys).

There are safer ways of [erasing masses of keys in Riak KV 2.9.1](https://github.com/basho/riak_kv/blob/riak_kv-2.9.1.1/docs/ReapErase.md), which are available regardless of backend (assuming the use of Tictac AAE).

As for $bucket or $key queries returning deleted keys, I suspect that this may well be true due to the fact that this is an "internal" leveldb query and within leveldb it wan't be able to distinguish between a Riak object and a riak tombstone.  The improvements in Riak 2.9.x handle this situation, and won't return deleted keys (unless you're looking for tombstones to reap).